# How can I test FairPlay encrypted streaming urls in Azure Media Player?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I know testing this on iOS device is an option but I want to make sure before I get to that the encrpytion config is good so I don't run into any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have read document about [Azure Media Player](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html), according description maybe you can open sites ([site 1](http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/),[site 2](http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/amp_editor.html)) to test your encrypted streaming urls by Safari Browser which installed in OSX Yosemite+.

Here is pic, you can refer it.

[image]